# Why is LibreOffice not detecting the theme?

Tags: windows, libreoffice, dark-mode

https://draculatheme.com/libreoffice

I followed the instructions and put `dracula.soc` in `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\share\palette`.

Closed and restarted LibreOffice Writer. Went into all the options. There is no "Dracula" theme/color scheme anywhere.

The instructions aren't even complete, but I've looked through all the options. I literally follow the exact instructions, yet nothing happens.

Comment: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118320

Comment: @Tetsujin Hmm?!

Answer (score 0):

In the instructions the last step is

> In case both color palette and theme should be added, run `install.sh` which executes the `cp` command for adding the color palette and then runs `add-dracula-application-colors.sh` to add the Dracula theme as an application color for LibreOffice.

You don't mention it, so I assume you didn't execute `install.sh`. I had the same problem as you, but running the script made it work, and now the theme is there. I also found the instructions confusing, as that final step was hidden behind Linux and macOS -specific instructions.